# Unable to Parse JSON data properly

Tags: android, json

I am getting below JSON data by querying URL

```
http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/jsonActors
```

But when I parse, I am only getting first set of data and not second one, not sure where am I making mistake. How to get all nodes from JSON array. Thanks for your help.

Below is my code :

```
        /**
         * getting Inbox JSON
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


            url = "http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/jsonActors" 


            Log.d(TAG , "URL IS:" + url);
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", params, false);

            Log.d("Parse", "Data : " + json.toString());


            try {

                data = json.getJSONArray("actors");

                    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

                        //Here I am getting all values one by one


                    }




            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch(Exception e){

            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        }

    }
```

Comment: In the code, nothing is there, where you are adding that to the list?

Comment: @NigamPatro - That is later part, at least the response of variable 'data' that I am logging is only giving me this much of value {"weekid":"16","stDate":"20160418","enDate":"20160424","stDay":"Mon","day":["MM","MM","NONE","NONE","NONE","NONE","NONE"],"fbFlag":"-1","twFlag":"-1","pcVpnFlag":"0"}. It should also give me 'week15' value

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have to set all the data separately to the some global variables and then use that in for loop.
try following code:

```
ArrayList<MyListEntity> subList;
for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
    //get the information JSON object
    String subIDInfo = objSub.getJSONObject(i).toString();
    //create java object from the JSON object
    MyListEntity cat = gson.fromJson(subIDInfo, MyListEntity.class);
    //add to country array list
    subList.add(cat);
    }
```

here MyListEntity  is the class of that global variables.In this you have to get and set the variables you want from JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Because in your `for` loop you are not doing anything with the parsed value. You need to store that value somewhere before iterating the loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
    String weekId = null;
    weekId = c.getString("weekid"); //store this value in a String array or ArrayList
}
```

Comment: That is second part, I am doing that. But the variable 'data' should have all values of json I posted. But it is only giving me this much "{"weekid":"16","stDate":"20160418","enDate":"20160424","stDay":"Mon","day":["MM","MM","NONE","NONE","NONE","NONE","NONE"],"fbFlag":"-1","twFlag":"-1","pcVpnFlag":"0"}"

Comment: @user45678 Then there is a problem with the server API. Did you test that API using a Rest Client?

Comment: Yup, I checked the same URL in some sample apps which parse JSON and it is giving me complete JSON value, not sure if I am missing something here

Comment: No, your code seems fine in that aspect. I'd recommend using a Rest Client like Postman and test the API once.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> weekId;

for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
    String weekId = null;
    weekId.add(c.getString("weekid")); 


}
```

Answer (score 0):

in `JSON` anything beginning with a `{` is a `JsonObject` and beginning with `[` is a `JsonArray`. Following this, refer below code:

```
jsonArray=fullJsonObject.getJsonArray("weeklydata");
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){  
   JSONObject obj=jsonArray.getJsonObject(i);
   /**this will give you the first object for i= 0 now (see below)**/                }
```

that means that, obj will be

```
obj={"weekid":"16","stDate":"20160418","enDate":"20160424","stDay":"Mon","day":["MM","MM","NONE","NONE","NONE","NONE","NONE"],"fbFlag":"-1","twFlag":"-1","pcVpnFlag":"0"}
```

now from this object `obj`, you can retrieve all strings using

```
String weekid=obj.getString("weekid");
String stDate=obj.getString("stDate");
```

and so on.

Comment: But that 'weeklydata' has two object, so I should get two object whereas I am getting only one when I log '{"weekid":"16","stDate":"20160418","enDate":"20160424","stDay":"Mon","day":["MM","MM","NONE","NONE","NONE","NONE","NONE"],"fbFlag":"-1","twFlag":"-1","pcVpnFlag":"0"}'

Comment: for the 1st loop you will get the first object, for the second you will get the second object. Now you can create an arraylist and add them one by one.

Comment: @user45678 please let me know if you find any problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fatch Json Array from your response..
Just Follow this Step:

```
JSONObject json=new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray JArrary= json.getJSONArray("weeklydata");
```

After that You need to Call for loop

```
for (int i= 0; i< JArrary.size(); i++) {
JSONObject obj= JArrary.getJSONObject(JArrary);
String weekid = obj.getString("weekid");
String stDate = obj.getString("stDate");
String enDate = obj.getString("enDate");
String stDay = obj.getString("stDay");
String fbFlag = obj.getString("fbFlag");
String twFlag = obj.getString("fbFlag");
String pcVpnFlag = obj.getString("pcVpnFlag");
JSONArray newArray= obj.getJSONArray("day");
String Day = newArray.toString();
}
```

Hope its Help you :)

Comment: than what you need @user45678

Comment: can you please mention in your quations @user45678

Answer (score 0):

Try Replacing your JSONArray with below:

```
JSONArray data = json.optJSONArray("weeklydata");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();


}

/**
 * getting Inbox JSON
 */
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


    url = "www.someurl.com"


    Log.d(TAG, "URL IS:" + url);
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", params, false);

    try {

        JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("weeklydata");
        //I am concerned here. Here it is only giving first set of data (week16) and not second one (week15)


        List<Weaklydata> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int a = 0; a < data.length(); a++) {

            Weaklydata weaklydata = new Weaklydata();
            JSONObject jsonObject1 = data.getJSONObject(a);

            weaklydata.setEnDate(jsonObject1.getString("enDate"));
            weaklydata.setFbFlag(jsonObject1.getString("fbFlag"));
            weaklydata.setTwFlag(jsonObject1.getString("pcVpnFlag"));
            weaklydata.setStDate(jsonObject1.getString("stDate"));
            weaklydata.setStDay(jsonObject1.getString("stDay"));
            weaklydata.setWeekid(jsonObject1.getString("twFlag"));
            weaklydata.setWeekid(jsonObject1.getString("weekid"));

            List<String> dayList = new ArrayList<>();

            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("day");

            for (int pos = 0; pos < jsonArray.length(); pos++) {
                dayList.add(jsonArray.getString(pos));
            }

            weaklydata.setDay(dayList);
            list.add(weaklydata);
        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
}
```

}

public class Weaklydata {

```
private String weekid;
private String stDate;
private String enDate;
private String stDay;
private List<String> day = new ArrayList<String>();
private String fbFlag;
private String twFlag;
private String pcVpnFlag;
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

/**
 * @return The weekid
 */
public String getWeekid() {
    return weekid;
}

/**
 * @param weekid The weekid
 */
public void setWeekid(String weekid) {
    this.weekid = weekid;
}

/**
 * @return The stDate
 */
public String getStDate() {
    return stDate;
}

/**
 * @param stDate The stDate
 */
public void setStDate(String stDate) {
    this.stDate = stDate;
}

/**
 * @return The enDate
 */
public String getEnDate() {
    return enDate;
}

/**
 * @param enDate The enDate
 */
public void setEnDate(String enDate) {
    this.enDate = enDate;
}

/**
 * @return The stDay
 */
public String getStDay() {
    return stDay;
}

/**
 * @param stDay The stDay
 */
public void setStDay(String stDay) {
    this.stDay = stDay;
}

/**
 * @return The day
 */
public List<String> getDay() {
    return day;
}

/**
 * @param day The day
 */
public void setDay(List<String> day) {
    this.day = day;
}

/**
 * @return The fbFlag
 */
public String getFbFlag() {
    return fbFlag;
}

/**
 * @param fbFlag The fbFlag
 */
public void setFbFlag(String fbFlag) {
    this.fbFlag = fbFlag;
}

/**
 * @return The twFlag
 */
public String getTwFlag() {
    return twFlag;
}

/**
 * @param twFlag The twFlag
 */
public void setTwFlag(String twFlag) {
    this.twFlag = twFlag;
}

/**
 * @return The pcVpnFlag
 */
public String getPcVpnFlag() {
    return pcVpnFlag;
}

/**
 * @param pcVpnFlag The pcVpnFlag
 */
public void setPcVpnFlag(String pcVpnFlag) {
    this.pcVpnFlag = pcVpnFlag;
}

public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
}

public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}
```

}